# How to set paper form that came from DeviceCapabilities?

Tags: c++, winapi, printing

I have a printer that has forms that cannot be retrieved via `EnumForms`. `EnumForms` only gets me the forms from the PrintServer. Via `DeviceCapabilities` with the DC_PAPERNAMES parameter I get the form (Super Long Paper) i need to set.

I tried to set the form like so

```
wcscpy(pDevMode->dmFormName, L"Super Long Paper");
pDevMode->dmFields |= DM_FORMNAME;
ResetDCW(hPrintDC, pDevMode);
```

This doesn't work.

Is it possible to get a value for this specific form that can be set via `pDevMode->dmPapersize` or is there another option how I can set a form that only shows up by using `DeviceCapabilities`?

I would appreciate every bit of advice in the right direction.

This has to work under Windows XP.

EDIT:

The programm should not show a dialog. Everything as to be set via code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found  the solution. You have to call `DeviceCapabilities` three times. Once with `DC_PAPERS`, once with `DC_PAPERNAMES`and once with `DC_PAPERSIZE`. Every call gives you an array with the form name, size and number (to set in the DevMode) for the printer supported forms. With these you can set the `dmPaperSize,`dmPaperLength`and`dmPaperWidth`Properties of the DevMode.